# httpd reverse proxy redirect with extra root directory name

Tags: apache, redirect, spring-security, wildfly

I deploy a website war in wildfly named testDom-0.1 with apache httpd reverse proxy on. After logging in successfully, the default successful URL in spring security is "/booking", but the browser always get "testDom-0.1/booking" and then complain 404 error, if manually change the url into /booking, the page can be accessed without problem.

```
http.formLogin()
.loginPage("/denglu").permitAll()
.defaultSuccessUrl("/booking",true)
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/testDom-0.1/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/testDom-0.1/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /testDom-0.1 /

        <proxy>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

The expected return url should be localhost/booking not localhost/testDom-0.1/booking

Comment: It's as if the ProxyPassReverse isn't working properly to rewrite any Location headers. Can you maybe tcpdump the traffic on port 8080 to see exactly what wildfly is sending to apache?

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you give me a hint about how can you fix this problem.